# Draw a circular transparent hole into UIView for given rect

Tags: swift, calayer, mask

I am trying to create a circular transparent hole into my UIview with the following code, and this code makes the correct hole based on given rect. In my situation I have few rects which are individual and few of them are overlapped,for all those rect which are getting overlapped and not getting transparent holes over intersection rect area because of fill rule kCAFillRuleEvenOdd.How can I modify the same code so it can work for individual rects and all other overlapped rect and create transparent holes into view?

```
let overlay = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width,height: height))
overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4)

// Create the path.
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: view.frame)
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = view.frame

for rectFrame in rects {
    // Create the frame for the circle.
    let rect = CGRect(x: rectFrame.origin.x, y: rectFrame.origin.y, width: 38, height: 38)

    // Append the circle to the path so that it is subtracted.
    path.append(UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect))
}

maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

// Set the mask of the view.
view.layer.mask = maskLayer

self.overlayLayer.addSubview(overlay)
```

Comment: Why are you using the even-odd rule? Try using the winding rule.

Comment: @ray mayoff,  I am not sure how I can use the winding rule instead of evenOdd, when I see the doc the winding rule is something "var usesEvenOddFillRule: Bool", Do you have any sample for this...

Comment: Sorry, I meant the non-zero rule. `maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleNonZero`.

Comment: with kCAFillRuleNonZero property I am not able to create any transparent hole..